# resize listbox in PySimpleGui based on length of list

Tags: listbox, size, pysimplegui

I'm trying to update the Listbox in PySimpleGUI to resize based on length of list but the `update(size=len(mylist)` says that size is not an allowed argument. Any work around to this?

I've seen some people try to make the window/layout into a function but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the height or the width of a `Listbox` element should not be revised after initialized, or the size of window will be also changed and maybe out of screen.

There's no option provided to change the height or the width of the Listbox element in PySimpleGUI, but you can do it by tkinter code, `element.Widget.configure(height=height, width=width)`.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

name_list = sorted(['James', 'Robert',  'John', 'Michael', 'David', 'William', 'Richard', 'Joseph', 'Thomas', 'Charles'])
layout = [
    [sg.Input('', key='Name'), sg.Button('Add')],
    [sg.Listbox(name_list, size=(20, len(name_list)), expand_x=True, key='Names')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
window['Name'].bind('<Return>', ' Return')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in ('Add', 'Name Return'):
        name = values['Name']
        if name and name not in name_list:
            name_list = sorted(name_list+[name])
            window['Names'].Widget.configure(height=len(name_list))
            window['Names'].update(values=name_list)
            window.move_to_center()

window.close()
```